# how to query all rows that don't have a combination data

Tags: oracle11g

Data I'm working on looks like below

```
abc  year  flag
---  ----  ----
a    2001  Y
a    2001  N
a    2001  N
b    2002  Y
b    2002  N
c    2002  N
m    2001  Y
d    2003  N
```

I need all rows that don't have a flag 'Y'  for 'abc' and 'year' combination.

result data should be :

```
abc  year  flag
---  ----  ---- 
c    2002  N
d    2003  N
```

Comment: Could you show us which queries did you try and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple application of ANTI-JOIN:

```
with
     inputs ( abc, yr, flag ) as (
       select 'a', 2001, 'Y' from dual union all 
       select 'a', 2001, 'N' from dual union all
       select 'a', 2001, 'N' from dual union all
       select 'b', 2002, 'Y' from dual union all
       select 'b', 2002, 'N' from dual union all
       select 'c', 2002, 'N' from dual union all
       select 'm', 2001, 'Y' from dual union all
       select 'd', 2003, 'N' from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the query).
-- SQL solution begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select abc, yr, flag
from   inputs
where  (abc, yr) not in (select abc, yr from inputs where flag = 'Y')
;

ABC    YR  FLAG
---  ----  ----
c    2002  N
d    2003  N
```